# ODE how to check if the kernel is empty

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

In class we are working on a type of problems called green function $G$, and we use it to solve second order ODE. What I have an issue is that for problems where the kernel of L is empty we use one approach to get to $G$, and if the kernel is non-empty we have a more complicated way. My problem in particular is that I do not know how to inspect when the kernel is empty.

Example. $y''+y=1$ with $y(0)=0$, $y(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$ has an empty kernel

Example $y''+y=f(x)$ with $y(0)=0$ $y(\pi)=0$ has a kernel spanned by $\sin(x)$.

From what I understand what we do is we take the homogeneous equation and solve with the boundary conditions. Can someone explain to me how we see when the kernel is empty and how we do it in general. Thank you for the time guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We take the homogeneous equation and **one** of the boundary conditions (which are also homogeneous) as an initial condition, and solve.  The result will be of the form $y = c f(t)$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.  If this always satisfies the other boundary condition, then the kernel is spanned by $f(t)$.
If it doesn't (unless $c=0$), the kernel is empty.

Thus in your first example, the general solution of $y'' + y = 0$ is 
$y = a \sin(t) + b \cos(t)$.  The initial condition $y(0) = 0$ makes it
$y = a \sin(t)$, and we see that $a \sin(\pi/2) = 0$ only if $a=0$, so the kernel here is empty.  But with $\pi$ instead of $\pi/2$ we have $a \sin(\pi) = 0$, so here the kernel is spanned by $\sin(t)$.